# Bad data notification without stopping automation

Tags: automationstudio, csv, notification

I have an automation that imports a csv from an external SFTP and processes it by splitting and augmenting the data into 2 data extensions. There is a chance that some rows in the original csv might be missing data. Instead of making the column non-nullable and stopping the whole automation, I would like an email sent to an admin that there are rows missing but complete the automation run. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting your import activity to 'Skip rows with bad data' will allow for the automation to continue if it finds a record with invalid data or a data-type mismatch between the CSV and the target data extension. If you do this while setting your field as 'non-nullable', it will not insert any empty records, and it will continue the import process without failing. You can also configure your import activity to send an email notification on completion. This will send you an email to let you know which records were not imported and why.

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly.